# Conditional operator from String field

Tags: sql

Source

```
ename  location  sal
A      X         10
A      x         20
B      y         30
B      x         40
```

ref_table

Reference

```
ename  location  sal    hike
A      x         '<30'   10%
B      y         '>30'   25%
```

For first record of Ref_table my logic should be

```
Select Sal 
from source a
left join
Ref_table B
where 
a.sal<=B.sal
```

For second record of Ref_table my logic should be

```
Select Sal 
from source a
left join
Ref_table B
where 
a.sal>=B.sal
```

Comment: which db are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Sal
from source a
left join Ref_table B on case when substring(B.Sal,1,1)='<' and a.sal<=cast(substring(B.sal,2,10) as int) then 1 when substring(B.Sal,1,1)='>' and a.sal>=cast(substring(B.sal,2,10) as int) then 1 else 0 end=1
```

Also be careful because you are using left join and where which will return only rows that meet your condition (similarly to inner join).

Comment: here then and else clause will returns the output right?

Comment: Because your join criterion is part of 'sal' column you must retrieve it and conditionally join tables, here I join tables only when value of the case...end equals 1, which is true for two possible cases 1) 'sal' contains '<'; 2) 'sal' contains '>'.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select
    s.sal,
    s.ename
from
    source s inner join
    ref_table r on
    s.ename = r.ename
where
    (ename = 'a' and s.sal<=r.sal) or
    (ename = 'b' and s.sal>=s.sal)
```